# like query in nested association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below is my User.rb

```
class User
  has_one :profile
  has_one :qualification
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Qualification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, I want to fetch users whose profile.name like params or qualification.name like params.

I am trying the following code but getting error:

```
User.joins(:profile, :qualification)
    .where("profiles.name like ?  
            or qualifications.name like ?", 
            "%#{params[:name]}%", 
            "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

I am using `Ruby 2.4,  Rails 5.1`

Below is the error:

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `qualifications` ON `qualifications`.`id` = `users`.`qualification_id` WHERE (profiles.name like %user9%) LIMIT 11
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%user9%) LIMIT 11' at line 1: SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `profiles` ON `profiles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `qualifications` ON `qualifications`.`id` = `users`.`qualification_id` WHERE (profiles.name like %user9%) LIMIT 11
```

Profile and Qualification table contain user_id as foreign key.
I am able to get the records by `User.joins(:profile, :qualification)` it creates a

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: seems like  you have added % inside
User.joins(:profile, :qualification).where("profiles.name like ?  or qualifications.name like ?", "%{params[:name]}%", "%{params[:name]}%")

Comment: @Tai: I have added the errors in the question

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma It is strange when no inner join between `user` and `profile`. Can you post `schema` and model of `user`, `profile` and `qualification`?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma what Tai said plus your query  with `to_sql`. It's very strange there's no mention of JOIN in the error.

Comment: @Tai: I have updated the question with association and error logs

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma I saw one problem in your query "%#{params[:name]%}" can't work. Please change it to "%#{params[:name]}%" and try again.

Comment: @Tai: It was typing problem, i have tried the same but no luck

Comment: Is there any special characters on `params[:name]`?

Comment: no, , I also tried User.joins(:profile).where("profiles.name like %user9%") but no luck

Comment: Done, It was typo error the above works, thanks @tai